# Is there a word for the sound the wind makes?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been in quiet spaces and heard the wind coming long before it gets to where I am. It is almost like a presence that is there at the edge of perception.

Comment: The wind sighs, whispers, whistles, howls, ...

Comment: Answers in the answer box please.

Answer (score 4):

**Howl** *verb*

If the wind howls, it blows with a long loud sound

**Sigh** *verb*

If the wind sighs, it makes a long soft low sound

**Sough** *verb*

If the wind soughs, it makes a soft noise like a sigh

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/what-the-wind-can-do)

Answer (score 4):

### [Psithurism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/psithurism)

> The sound of wind in the trees and rustling of leaves.

(The Free Dictionary)